# Why are minus signs not working in this equation?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

In the below equation I'm writing, 2 minus signs are not visible, why is that?

```
$\phi (s, \lambda) = C
\frac{
1 + \beta^2 − 2 \beta cos( \frac{2 \pi s}{\lambda} )
}{
\lambda^5 \exp(
\frac{
h c
}{
\lambda k B T
} − 1)
}
$
```

Comment: Those are not really minus signs. Delete them and replace them with the real minus sign `-` and they will show.

Comment: Wait, I just tried retyping them and it worked. Why is there a difference?

Comment: Because the symbol you had is not recognized as the minus sign; in fact, it is not recognized at all.

Comment: You haven't provided a usable fragment (or even said that you are using LaTeX the `\frac`implies that you are) LaTeX does not silently drop characters, assuming your file is UTF-8 encoded then had you declared `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` you would have an error message `! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:− not set up for use with LaTeX.`  If you had not declared utf8 the bytes of the utf8 encoding would be interpreted directly as input for the 7bit cm fonts resulting in warnings in the log `Missing character: There is no � in font cmr7!
Missing character: There is no � in font cmr7!`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that the character you are using is the Unicode minus sign which is not recognized by LaTeX with your current settings; it is `U+2212 MINUS` (most probably a result from a copy-paste). Replace the symbols with the LaTeX minus signs and they will show.

I took the liberty of modifying a little your expression to produce a better result for an on-line expression (perhaps you could consider showing this as a displayed expression):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\phi (s, \lambda) = C
\bigl( 1 + \beta^{2} - 2 \beta \cos(2 \pi s\lambda^{-1} ) \bigr) /
\bigl( \lambda^{5} \exp( \frac{ h c }{ \lambda k B T} - 1) \bigr)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that for the cosine function you should use `\cos` and not just `cos`.

Comment: actually the character was U+2212 MINUS   :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the identification.

Comment: @barbarabeeton You're right. I've changed the redaction (I hope it's OK now). Thanks.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- yup.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Any ideas why such a "basic" symbol is not included in `utf8`?

Answer (score 7):

You should get an error message like

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:− not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

unless you aren't loading `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (which is recommended); in this case the `.log` file would report

```
Missing character: There is no <E2> in font cmr7!
Missing character: There is no <88> in font cmr7!
Missing character: There is no <92> in font cmr7!
```

twice, because you have two minus signs.

The Unicode character U+2212 is not defined in `utf8enc.dfu`, but it's easy to add a definition for it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}

\begin{document}
$\phi (s, \lambda) = C
\frac{
1 + \beta^2 − 2 \beta \cos( \frac{2 \pi s}{\lambda} )
}{
\lambda^5 \exp(
\frac{
h c
}{
\lambda k B T
} − 1)
}
$
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}

% The offending character in the first argument
% and a hyphen in the second argument!
\newunicodechar{−}{-}     

\begin{document}
$\phi (s, \lambda) = C
\frac{
1 + \beta^2 − 2 \beta \cos( \frac{2 \pi s}{\lambda} )
}{
\lambda^5 \exp(
\frac{
h c
}{
\lambda k B T
} − 1)
}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]