# Negative exponent not displayed using the subfigure environment from subcaption

Tags: math-mode, subcaption

Consider this simple MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption} %sub figures
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Test1}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{with $10^{−4}$ and a mass fraction cutoff of $10^{−30}$}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subcaptionbox}{Test2}[\linewidth]{
    \centering
}
\end{subcaptionbox}
\caption{$10^{-4}$ and a mass fraction cutoff of $10^{-30}$}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

On my system (TeXstudio 2.5.2 (SVN 3661)
Using Qt Version 4.8.1, compiled with Qt 4.8.1 R), this is displayed as the following [image]

Why are the negative signs in the exponents missing when using subfigure?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have to use the common hyphen and not U+2212 MINUS SIGN. There is a very similar problem in another question: [Why are minus signs not working in this equation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177468/)

Comment: As I tested in my system, your minus signs in the first case are not actual minus signs. Simply delete them and then retype using the key at the right of 0.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!

I do wonder where those came from now...